# É possível instanciar uma classe sem armazená-la em uma variável?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, instanciar-objeto

Normalmente eu faço assim:

```
$a = new MinhaClass($Parametro);
```

Tem como fazer isso sem criar a variável `$a` ? Só com o `new`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, dá, só que não tem muita utilidade porque o objeto morrerá em seguida já que não quis armazená-lo. Em alguns casos pode ser suficiente, mas se for, provavelmente não precisava ter criado a classe.

Por exemplo, se só precisa instanciar o objeto, chamar um método e não fazer mais nada é um caso típico onde não deveria ser uma classe. Por isso minha resposta não fala disto.

```
class MinhaClass {}
new MinhaClass($Parametro);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y2PTye). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mvoerqet-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Instance.php).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
(new MyClass());
```

Você também pode executar métodos, por exemplo:

```
(new MyClass())->init();
```

E até usar dentro de funções, como num `echo`:

```
echo (new Auth())->getToken();
```